# If $X$ is bounded, then $f(X)$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Question:

> Let $f:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n$ be continuous. If $X\subset \mathbb
>  R^m$ is bounded, then $f(X)\subset \mathbb R^n$ is bounded.

I found a counterexample:

[image]

What am I missing? Any hint to prove this question? thanks

Thanks

Comment: In your "counterexample" $f$ is not defined and not continuous at the right border of $X$

Comment: Hint: The closure of $X$ is compact.

Answer (score 5):

What you're missing is that the assumption is  $f$ is continuous on all of $\mathbb R^m$, not just on $X$.